# How to Add HTML5 Intellisense Support to Visual Studio 2010 SP1?

Tags: css, visual-studio, html, intellisense

How to Add HTML5 Intellisense Support to Visual Studio 2010 Professional Edition SP1?

I've installed this: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d771cbc8-d60a-40b0-a1d8-f19fc393127d but nothing happened.

For example when I type `<convas` on the Visual studio source view of a page, I expect the list of its attributes to be listed, etc.

Comment: `canvas` might yield better results.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `<canvas>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are in an html editor, there is a box at the top of the page to select the validation, it defaults to XHTML (I think), and you can change it to HTML5.

[image]

Comment: I changed **tools->options->Text Editor-> html-> validation to HTML5** but still Intellisense not working. please help

Answer (score 2):

In visual studio Menu Options Go to Tools-> Text Editor-> HTML-> Validation-> Target and select HTML5 in drop down if you already download and install the [HTML 5 Intellisense for Visual Studio 2010 and 2008](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d771cbc8-d60a-40b0-a1d8-f19fc393127d)